# .each for :checked selector not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function () {
    $.each('input:checked', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        alert(tr.id);
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th width="40">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"></th>
    <th width="120">From</th>
    <th width="500">Subject</th>
    <th width="140">Date</th>
</tr>

<tr replytoid="3" messageid="2664" id="15" class="messageNew">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"></td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>3/14/2012 1:09:04 PM</td>
</tr>
```

I need this to loop through each checked box (excluding the one inside the `<th>`).  I then need it to find the `<tr>` the checkbox is inside of, and grab that id.  I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: if you use firebug, please get rid of `alert()` and use `console.log()`

Comment: What do you mean "not working properly"?

Comment: @jon it send an alert for every single check box (around 20 currently) not just the 2 I had checked for testing).  It also will not alert the id of the `<tr>`

Comment: @Alp thank you, I had no idea of that feature.

Comment: @JamesWilson Just keep in mind that `console.log()` will not work in IE until you open the console (if you are using a version that has the console). Otherwise, it will throw an error and possibly not execute code. Even with that in mind, `console.log()` is far better than using alerts because it will not interfere with your code in the same way that alerts will.

Comment: @KevinB can i leave these in for production, or would it break the code if they use IE or FF without firebug?  Should they all be commented out or erased after i am done?

Comment: @JamesWilson They should be commented out for production environments, otherwise it will break code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using the correct version of `$.each` for this scenario. Try this:

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function () {
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        alert(tr[0].id);
    });
});
```

Also, `tr` is a jquery object, use `[0]` or `.get(0)` to get back to the dom element to get it's ID property.

Comment: Shouldn't `tr[0].id` be `tr[0].attr('id')`?

Comment: @j08691 No because `TableCell` elements do not have a `attr` method. However, `tr.attr('id')` and `tr.prop('id')` would work the same way as `tr[0].id`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do this

```
$('input:checked').each(function(i, input) {
    var tr = $(input).closest('tr');
    alert(tr.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, with your code:

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function () {
                $.each('input:checked', function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    alert(tr.id);
                });
            });
```

the `tr` variable is a jQuery object, and to get the `id` you'd need to use the `attr()` method:

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function () {
                $.each('input:checked', function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    alert(tr.attr('id'));
                });
            });
```

Also, your use of `each()` is problematic. If you amend to the following:

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function() {
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        console.log(tr.attr('id'));
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k6E4S/).

It *seems* to work, though since you didn't specify in what way it "didn't work," it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` and `.each()` are different. You want to be using `.each()` which iterates jquery objects.

```
$('input:checked').each(function(idx, el){
    // Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('#deleteMessage').click(function () {
                $('td input:checked').each(function () {
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        alert(tr.id);
                    });
            });
```

to loop through each checked input.  Adding td to the selector will exclude the input within the `<th>`

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  Now I'm not sure who to give the answer to... derek or KevinB

Comment: glad I could help, but Kevin did answer it first.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `tr.prop('id')` instead of `tr.id`.